# SQL Query with a MAX and Nested Join

Tags: sql, join, nested, max

I have what should be a very simple query where I'm trying to get the Part Revision of a Part based on it's max effective date but I keep getting more than 1 result.  Would be so great if someone could take a look and tell me what I'm missing?  Below is query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Erp.PartRev.PartNum
    , Erp.PartMtl.RevisionNum
    , Erp.PartRev.EffectiveDate
FROM            
    Erp.PartRev INNER JOIN
    Erp.PartMtl ON Erp.PartRev.Company = Erp.PartMtl.Company 
    AND Erp.PartRev.PartNum = Erp.PartMtl.PartNum 
    AND Erp.PartRev.RevisionNum = Erp.PartMtl.RevisionNum
WHERE        
    (Erp.PartRev.EffectiveDate =
        (SELECT MAX(EffectiveDate)
        FROM PartRev AS PartRev_1
        WHERE (PartRev_1.PartNum = PartMtl.PartNum) 
        AND (PartRev_1.RevisionNum = PartMtl.RevisionNum)))
GROUP BY 
    Erp.PartRev.PartNum
    , Erp.PartRev.RevisionNum   
    , Erp.PartMtl.RevisionNum
    , Erp.PartRev.EffectiveDate
HAVING (Erp.PartRev.PartNum = N'100-220-2022-01')
```

and results below:

[enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVsQn.png)

Expect to see record with most recent date and get 3 records instead of one.

Here is a better example with more than one part and multiple records for each.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Erp.PartRev.PartNum
    , Erp.PartMtl.RevisionNum
    , Erp.PartRev.EffectiveDate
FROM            
    Erp.PartRev INNER JOIN
    Erp.PartMtl ON Erp.PartRev.Company = Erp.PartMtl.Company 
    AND Erp.PartRev.PartNum = Erp.PartMtl.PartNum 
    AND Erp.PartRev.RevisionNum = Erp.PartMtl.RevisionNum
WHERE        
    (Erp.PartRev.EffectiveDate =
        (SELECT MAX(EffectiveDate)
        FROM PartRev AS PartRev_1
        WHERE (PartRev_1.PartNum = PartMtl.PartNum) 
        AND (PartRev_1.RevisionNum = PartMtl.RevisionNum)))
GROUP BY 
    Erp.PartRev.PartNum
    , Erp.PartRev.RevisionNum   
    , Erp.PartMtl.RevisionNum
    , Erp.PartRev.EffectiveDate
HAVING        (Erp.PartRev.PartNum LIKE N'100-220-2022%')
```

[screenshot of results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR1gJ.png)

Comment: GROUP BY combined with SELECT DISTINCT is very odd.

Answer (score 0):

(The screenshot looks like SSMS so I'm making the assumption you're using SQL Server)

My guess is you're getting 3 results are because there are 3 companies with the same part number.  In that case if you want to ensure one result you'd need to specify for which Company and you can do that without any joins or group by:

```
SELECT TOP 1
 PartNum,
 RevisionNum,
 EffectiveDate
FROM            
  Erp.PartRev 
WHERE 
  PartNum = N'100-220-2022-01'
  and Comany = '???'
ORDER BY EffectiveDate Desc
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Actually we only have one company so that's not it :-/ and I'm using MSSQL

Comment: @Michael you are right it should be simple.  No joins or subquery or group by required based on the question described.  Since one company only, remove the second condition on the where clause in my answer and you'll have the latest revision for a part.

Comment: I only added that single part to show as an example.  If I have multiple different parts, the TOP 1 only pulls the maximum date for that item.  I have many more parts in my system where I require it to pull the RevisionNum of the maximum date.